# testing ipad app on device using firewire cable rather than USB

Tags: xcode, firewire

I am trying to find out if I can test my app written in `XCode` on my `iPad` using a `firewire` cable rather than the USB cable. A slightly random question I know but I am working in a remote area in Africa and need a cable sent to me. A firewire cable is on offer - does anyone know if it will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this? I don't think it will work.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2537899?start=15&tstart=0

Specifically these lines:

3rd post down by: Michael Fryd

> Current iDevices no longer have the circuitry to charge or communicate off the FW pins.
>
> When you plug your iDevice into a FW style charger you will not hurt your iDevice.   The higher FW voltage is on connector pins that are not connected inside your iPad.